# scrartcl / scrletter: applying pagestyle of firstpage to successive pages

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrletter

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{scrletter}

\setkomavar{fromname}{Best son}
\setkomavar{backaddress}{Smaland 3, Childrentown}

\let\letterpagemark\pagemark

\setkomavar{firstfoot}{%
    \begin{tabular}{p{0.95\textwidth}p{0.05\textwidth}}
        a beautiful table & \pagemark/\letterlastpage\\
    \end{tabular}
}

\setkomavar{nextfoot}{\usekomavar{firstfoot}}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Mom\\Parentstreet 1\\Hell}

\opening{Dear Mom,}

\lipsum[1-4]

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

produces:

[image]

Why does `\nextfoot` not alter the appearance of footers on pages of number > 1? Due to *reasons*, I would prefer to have the same footer style on all pages of the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KOMA variable `nextfoot` would be used with page style `letter`. But the default page style for the second letter page is `plain.letter`. Therefore you see only the page number in footer of page 2.

You could redefine `\letterpagestyle`:

```latex
\setkomavar{nextfoot}{\usekomavar{firstfoot}}
\renewcommand*{\letterpagestyle}{letter}% default is `plain.letter`
```

or you could use

```latex
\setkomavar{nextfoot}{\usekomavar{firstfoot}}
\AtBeginLetter{\cfoot*{\usekomavar{nextfoot}}}
```

or

```latex
\AtBeginLetter{\cfoot*{\usekomavar{firstfoot}}}
```

But note that both the position and the width of the footer differ between the first letter page and the other pages. Also the font settings are different.

If the footer on all letter pages should be the same (including position, width and font), you could redefine the pair of page styles `letter` (i.e. style `letter` and its plain style `plain.letter`) and change the style of the first letter page to `plain.letter` (or its alias `plain`). Note that the default page style of the first letter page is `empty`, i.e. `firstfoot` and `firsthead` are not part of a page style.

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{scrletter}

\setkomavar{fromname}{Best son}
\setkomavar{backaddress}{Smaland 3, Childrentown}

\let\letterpagemark\pagemark

\renewpairofpagestyles{letter}{%
  \clearpairofpagestyles
  \ifoot[text in inner footer]{}
  \ofoot*[\pagemark/\letterlastpage]{}
  \setkomafont{pagefoot}{\normalfont}%
  \KOMAoptions{footwidth=\useplength{firstfootwidth}}% change foot width for letter and plain.letter
}

% change vertical position of footer in style plain.letter:
\ForEachLayerOfPageStyle*{plain.letter}{%
  \Ifstrstart{#1}{plain.letter.foot}
     {\ModifyLayer[voffset={\useplength{firstfootvpos}}]{#1}}{}%
}
% the same can be done for page style letter (if this style is used too)

% use style plain.letter on first letter page, too
\newcommand*\originalopening{}
\let\originalopening\opening
\renewcommand*{\opening}[1]{%
  \originalopening{#1}%
  \thispagestyle{plain}% plain is an alias of plain.letter while page style pair letter is active
}
\KOMAoptions{firstfoot=false}% remove the default footer from first letter page

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Mom\\Parentstreet 1\\Hell}
\opening{Dear Mom,}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! I'm aware that I'm not the first one to [request](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196360/scrlttr2-make-second-page-footer-match-first-page-footer) [something](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/393849/footer-of-letter-also-in-the-second-page) [like](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289076/header-and-footer-does-not-show-on-second-page-scrlttr2) [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313344/scrlttr2-set-nextfoot-set-to-same-as-firstfoot). Could you please show how to do the vertical positioning with `scrartcl`? Couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Do you want to use the width and the position from the footer of the first page? Or the footer of the next pages?

Comment: Both position and size of the footer shown on the first page seem fine to me.

Comment: See my updated answer.